# How to select by the word in the terminal with quick keys?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, text

I'm currently making a switch from my old Macbook to a new and shiny Ubuntu (Purism) Laptop. Things go pretty well, but I'm having trouble selecting text in the terminal.

When I'm in a text in any normal program (browser, LibreOffice or any other text editor) I often want to select text using my keys instead of the mouse. To do that I can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then use the arrow keys to move left or right to select the text that I want. When I want to do the same, but select per word (which goes a lot quicker) I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and then select the words that I want using the left and right key. This works perfectly.

I now want to do the same in the terminal, but I can't get it working. When I hold just the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and move left and right it jumps words like I expect it to. But when I then hold the shift, if simply prints a `D` for the left arrow key and a `C` for the right arrow key.

Does anybody know why this is? And more importantly, does anybody know how I can get the behaviour I want where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> selects the word left of the cursor in the terminal?

Comment: Doesn't Purism ship with PureOS and not Ubuntu?

Comment: From the help (https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/txt-select-text.html.en), all options require a mouse. Or you can use `screen`/`tmux`.

Comment: @DKBose - Yes, but I wiped it and installed Ubuntu. I like to run the same as on my servers.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Thanatos](https://superuser.com/users/39876/thanatos) on [SuperUser Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/) it looks like it is not possible to do that with the default gnome terminal.

There is nothing about word selection shortcuts in the gnome terminal preferences.

Please see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/555886/why-cant-i-highlight-text-in-a-linux-terminal-emulator-with-shiftarrow-keys) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Ubuntu terminal and I just discovered that you can use alt instead of ctrl to delete blocks of text.
Hope it helps